# Trueskill Through Time - StackOverflowException

Tags: f#

I'm trying to understand more about the Trueskill Through Time paper.  Unfortunately my knowledge of F# is none existent and this is the only language code is currently available for.

When running the compiled program on the small sample chess database I receive the error "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException".

I believe the offending line is probably is within Chess.fs and is

```
(playerSkillsPerPlayer,logZ)
```

I was hoping someone out there may be able to assist further.

Comment: Which Visual Studio/F# version do you use to compile it? Can you at least give a reference to the code base including `Chess.fs`?

Comment: Apologies, thought I'd included the link. http://blogs.technet.com/b/apg/archive/2008/04/05/trueskill-through-time.aspx

Comment: The version you refer to is outdated. Can you try to compile and run this updated version on Visual Studio 2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2012/04/19/updated-version-of-quot-trueskill-through-time-quot-bayesian-inference-code.aspx?

Comment: In addition to pad's suggestion, make sure to compile in Release mode (or turn tail calls on before compiling in Debug mode).  Otherwise tail recursive functions may cause stack overflows, which could easily be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Latest version downloaded and compiled with VS2010.  Same problem but only when I don't use the -no-safe option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, even with the 2012 version of the TrueSkill Through Time code. I suspect it has to do with the code in `SqlSchema.fs`, but I am not sure.
In any case, I decided to modify the code a little bit to save the results to a CSV file: https://github.com/lucasmaystre/ChessAnalysis

This version works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with the Mono framework.

**Edit**: I have just released a Python library called [kickscore](https://github.com/lucasmaystre/kickscore). It is a strict generalization of TTT, so I think it might be useful to people trying to understand TTT in more details.